# Golang - read a streaming .mp4 from amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, go, amazon-s3, wowza

My aim is to setup a streaming video from a mobile phone to my API and I need to send each frame of the stream to an other script which will analyze the frames. In the end I want the video to be stored on the server.

As I've got no knowledge about streaming protocols (especially between a mobile and a server) I've requested the help of freelancers who had set up a wowza instance.

Thus, through this wowza, when you start recording on your mobile I can see `myStream.mp4` and `myStream.mp4.tmp` appearing on the S3 bucket.

So now, I've tried the s3.GetObject method with this flow:

```
svc := s3.New(session.New(), &aws.Config{Region: aws.String("region1"), Credentials: creds})

params := &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("bucket-name"),
    Key:    aws.String("mypath/myStream.mp4"),
}

result, err := svc.GetObject(params)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

_, err = io.Copy(os.Stdout, result.Body)
if err == io.EOF {
    fmt.Println("END OF FILE \\o/")
}
defer result.Body.Close()
```

But it get the object at an instant T.

**So, I've 2 questions:**

- Do you know a way to "read" the file while it's streaming?
- I've the feeling the return will be bytes when my script is waiting for pixels.. Which could be cool if I have .mp4 frames and I'm a bit clueless about what to look for.

Comment: A file is always a series of bytes by definition -- there's isn't a concept of "pixels" at that level. Not to mention, mp4 is a container which muxes audio and video streams, so there is no raw pixel data there either. You need to pass the data to a program (or library) that knows how to decode it.

Comment: I assume ffmpeg could do the work on this side

Comment: Yes, ffmeg could decode things. You also have the problem that s3 is an eventually consistent object store, so you can't "stream" through it. An object is either there, or it isn't. If the file is uploaded in chunks, you may be able to piece it together yourself. Also note that because s3 is only eventually consistent, you may find things out of order, stale, or appear much later than expected.

Comment: Yeah this is something I realised. Which is why I'm wondering why wowza recommends to store the file in S3 and then proceed from here to distribute the stream.
I'm quite lost and documentation about how to process is quite vague and hard to deal with.

Comment: Wowza can stream from existing video files in S3, but for ingestion of videos I'd expect all streaming to happen to the EC2 server(s) running Wowza and from there the video would be uploaded to S3 when complete (not before).

Comment: Interesting, which make me wondering that I really need to establish a proxy handling the correct protocol, and receive the video streaming from wowza. Makes more sens this way, I was blindly following the freelancers.

Comment: You CAN stream from S3, in a sense. At work here, we have built a stream decoder for zipped up xml files we need from a third party that are like 500gb (too big to DL and unzip). Because S3 supports resumable downloads, you can request chunks at a time (say 1mb) which can then be put in a `Reader` and read bytes at a time. It's a little complicated, but you have a few goroutines queue up a few chunks concurrently (however many works well without interruption), while the main routine uses the chunks of data. S3 allows an offset and a size, which allows you to fetch arbitrary pieces of the file.

Comment: In your case you would probably want to fetch chunk sizes anywhere from 32k-512k, though it would take experimentation to determine the chunk size, and how many you want to queue up. It gets more complicated when you try to account for various network speeds and reliability. But it can be done. EDIT, I just read that you are uploading this to S3, it supports resumable uploads too.